# Why restart() must be in try() in this Java program?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, restart, bufferedwriter, finally

Would you please borrow your wisdom a little bit for me?

I am now looking for the reason why restart() method in [add word mode] must be in finally{} section,
but I still don't figure out why. For now, both ways can be compiled either I put restart() in try{} or finally{}.  The thing is if I input it in try{}, this program doesn't show me the word that I input in [add word mode] when I choose [look all words mode]. If I put it in Finally{}, It works well but I am also worried because I was learned that finally{} section is only for close() method... But It works well! Why?

Another little question is, if i close BufferedReader(br) at finally{} section in addword(), It shows message of restart() and start(). After showing them, The program ends without accepting my keyboard input. Why?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException; 


public class EngDic{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
    Dictionary1 dic1 = new Dictionary1();
    dic1.start();
    }
    catch(IOException e){}
    }
}

class Dictionary1 {     

FileWriter write_target= null;
FileReader read_target= null;
BufferedReader br = null;
BufferedWriter bw= null;


void start() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Welcome!");
    System.out.println("What are you going to do?");
    System.out.println("1.add word 2.search word  3. look all words 4.exit");

    int sel = System.in.read()-48; //my input through keyboard will be set as sel.
    System.in.skip(2);

    switch (sel){
        case 1:addword();
                break;      

        case 2:searchword();
                break;

        case 3:lookall();
                break;

        case 4:System.exit(0);
                break;

        default:
            System.out.println("no such number!");
            System.exit(0);
    }       
}

void addword(){

    try{    

        br  =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        write_target = new FileWriter("voca.txt",true);
        bw= new BufferedWriter(write_target);

        System.out.println("[add word mode] has been selected. Please enter the words");
        System.out.println("CTR+Z means the end of input!");
        String line;
        while ((line=br.readLine()) !=null){
            System.out.println(line);
            bw.write(line);
            bw.newLine();                           
        }
            //restart();     

    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("-----error reason ------");   
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("-----error reason ------");
    }

    finally {   
                //if (br != null)               try{br.close();}                 catch(IOException e){} 
                if (bw != null)               try{bw.close();}               catch(IOException e){}                         
                restart();      
    }       
}

void  searchword(){
    try{
        System.out.println("[search word mode] has been selected. Please enter the words");
        read_target= new FileReader("voca.txt");
        br= new BufferedReader(read_target);

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String search_word =input.nextLine();

        String line;
        boolean flag = false;
        while ((line=br.readLine()) !=null){

            String[] searched = line.split("/");
                if (searched[0].equals(search_word)){
                    System.out.println("the meaning of the word you typed is " + searched[1]);  
                    flag = true;
                }
        }
        if (!(flag)){
            System.out.println("There's no such word!");
        }
        restart();

    }               
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("-----error------");   
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("-----error------");
    }

    finally { 
                //if (br != null)               try{br.close();}                 catch(IOException e){}
                if (bw !=null)               try{bw.close();}            catch(IOException e){}     

    }

}
/*look all words mode method */
void  lookall() {   
    System.out.println("[look all words mode] has been selected. Please enter the words");

    try{
        read_target= new FileReader("voca.txt");
        br= new BufferedReader(read_target);

        String line;
        while ((line=br.readLine()) !=null){
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        restart();           
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("-----error------");   
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("-----error------");
    }

    finally {
        //if (br != null)               try{br.close();}                 catch(IOException e){}
        if (bw !=null)               try{bw.close();}            catch(IOException e){}                         
    }
}

void restart(){
    try{    
        System.out.println("----------restart--------------");
        start();
    }
    catch (IOException e){}
}

}
```

Comment: Could you briefly describe what your program trying to achieve?

Comment: It's about English dictionay Program. If I input word/meaning in [add word mode], I can search the meaning of it by typing word in [word search mode]!